# Order theory from categorical point of view

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, order-theory

On p. 12 of [*Introduction to Lattices and Order*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_to_Lattices_and_Order/vVVTxeuiyvQC?hl=en) by Davey and Priestley, the authors give a 1-paragraph description of Category Theory, and then write:

> We do not have sufficient need to call on the theory of categories to warrant setting up its formalism here, but it would be wrong not to acknowledge its subliminal influence.

I find the authors' choice here hugely disappointing.  Can someone recommend an introduction to order theory that *does* use category theory in its presentation?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I feel like I should say that this is an excellent textbook (and what you refer to as "hugely disappointing" is a perfectly sensible choice of presentation on part of the authors) and you should not let this dissuade you from reading it if you are indeed interested in learning about lattices and order.

Comment: I completely agree with @Pilcrow. Moreover, it's a very good exercise to read this book (which largely goes without categorical language) and try to reformulate everything categorically _yourself_! I certainly got a lot out of doing exactly that. The key thing to remember is that posets can be viewed as (thin) categories, and order preserving maps as functors. You may find inspiration [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91377/the-category-of-posets) and [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial%20order).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: Thank you for the first link!  As for the second link, alas, I find ncat *completely unusable*.  In fact, I am utterly *gobsmacked* by the thought that *anyone* finds it at all useful.  For me at least it is the canonical example of "the rabbit hole."  (I have tried *really hard* to find a way to read ncat, without success.  Eventually, I figured out why: ncat would reduce to gibberish if one removed its hyperlinking feature.  This realization finally convinced me that *I* at least could never get anything out of ncat.)

Comment: I unironically owe the nlab at least half of my proficiency in category theory precisely because of the many rabbitholes I was forced to follow in order to make sense of what I was reading. Keep in mind that the quality of writing varies a lot through pages... Also, have you looked at te first chapter of [this book](https://assets.cambridge.org/97805218/34148/toc/9780521834148_toc.pdf) already? It seems it does exactly what you ask for, order theory from a category-theoretic standpoint.

Comment: @fosco: Thank you!  The link in your comment indeed does look very promising!

Comment: that book is "old", but I am teaching category theory *right now*, this semester, having in mind precisely the "[negative thinking](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/negative+thinking)" of introducing constructions in posets as if they were category-theoretic. For example, giving the definition of $\bigvee S$ for a subset $S\subseteq P$ of a poset I called it a "universal property". ;-)

Comment: @kjo fwiw I felt the same way about nlab at one point, but now I often read the nlab page first when learning about a new concept, finding it often the most readable introduction. The shift sort of happens subliminally if you get into category theory enough.

Comment: @N.Virgo: Thank you for sharing your experience with nlab.  I conjecture that this subliminal process you describe may be analogous to the process that happens to the learner of a foreign language L.  Even when the learner knows L's grammar, it is initially impossible for him/her to read, e.g. the news, in L.  The reason is insufficient vocabulary.  As the learner learns more and more vocabulary, he/she reach a critical mass of it (or, perhaps more accurately, a ["percolation threshold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold)) beyond which he/she can read the news. ...

Comment: @N.Virgo: ...Beyond this critical point the learner knows enough vocabulary to understand enough of the text to allow him/her to infer the remaining unknown words from context.  Of course, for the typical foreign language learner there are many, many resources dedicated exclusively to reaching this percolation threshold ([e.g.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mastering_French_Vocabulary/675dAAAACAAJ?hl=en)).  If my conjecture is correct, you must have had ways *other than* nlab to build up your "category theory vocabulary."

Comment: @kjo that's absolutely true - I worked my way through quite a stack of textbooks and papers before nlab started being helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather idiosyncratic in the topics it covers, but you might get something out of Fong and Spivak's [Seven Sketches in Compositionality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05316). It's a textbook on applied category theory, but it begins with preorders and only later generalises to categories. The book has a tendency to try and build suspense, so the connection to categories isn't made explicit at first (it doesn't even give the defintion of a category until several chapters in), but the connection is very much there and gets revealed more explicitly later on.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer!  I particularly appreciate the heads-up about the authors' cuteness with suspense.  I find that sort of thing infuriating, but I think your forewarning will go a long way to blunt this annoyance.